# Отображается все в одной строке, нужно 4 в строку и дальнейшее продолжение на следующую строку

Tags: битрикс

Отображается все в одной строке, нужно 4 в строку и дальнейшее продолжение на следующую строку. Все это в битриксе.

так выглядит шаблон компонента catalog.section

```html
<div class="card-deck">
  <?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arElement):?>

    <?
 $this->AddEditAction($arElement['ID'], $arElement['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arParams["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
 $this->AddDeleteAction($arElement['ID'], $arElement['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arParams["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BCS_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
 ?>
      <!-- Card -->
      <div class="col-lg-3 card mb-4" id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arElement['ID']);?>">
        <!--Card image-->
        <div class="card-img">
          <div class="card-img__header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="card-like"></div>
            <div class="card-hit active">хит продаж</div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-img__product">
            <img src="<?=$arElement[" PREVIEW_PICTURE "]["SRC "]?>" alt="Card image cap">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Card content-->
        <div class="card-body">
          <!--Title-->
          <a href="<?=$arElement[" DETAIL_PAGE_URL "]?>">
            <h4 class="card-title"><b><?=$arElement["NAME"]?></b></h4>
          </a>
          <?foreach($arElement["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"] as $pid=>$arProperty):?>
            <div class="card-text">
              <p>Артикул:
                <?if(is_array($arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"]))
           echo implode("&nbsp;/&nbsp;", $arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"]);
           elseif($arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"] === true)
           echo "&nbsp;";
           else
           echo $arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"];?>
              </p>

              <p>материал: саше</p>
              <p>вес/объем: 10 мл</p>
            </div>
            <?endforeach?>
              <?foreach($arResult["PRICES"] as $code=>$arPrice):?>
                <div class="card-price d-flex align-items-center">
                  <?if($arPrice = $arElement["PRICES"][$code]):?>
                    <?if($arPrice["DISCOUNT_VALUE"] < $arPrice["VALUE"]):?>
                      <p>от </p>
                      <?else:?>
                        <h4 class="cprice"><b><?=$arPrice["PRINT_VALUE"]?></b></h4>
                        <?endif?>
                          <?else:?>
                            &nbsp;
                            <?endif;?>
                              <p>руб.</p>
                              <p>упаковка</p>
                              <div id="card-question" data-description="Количество товара Вы всегда можете отредактировать в корзине. Окончательная стоимость товара после обработки заказа менеджером"><img src="/bitrix/templates/.default/img/product-info-icon.png" alt="question"></div>
                </div>
                <?endforeach;?>
                  <?if(count($arResult["PRICES"]) > 0):?>

                    <?if($arElement["CAN_BUY"]):?>
                      <button href="<?echo $arElement[" BUY_URL "]?>" type="button" class="card-btn d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <img src="/bitrix/templates/.default/img/cart-white-icon.png" alt="trash">
          <p><?echo GetMessage("CATALOG_BUY")?></p>
         </button>
                      <?elseif((count($arResult["PRICES"]) > 0) || is_array($arElement["PRICE_MATRIX"])):?>
                        <?endif?>

                          <p class="bay-hover"><a href="#"><b>Купить в 1 клик</b></a></p>
                          <?endif;?>
        </div>
        <!-- / Card -->
      </div>
      <?endforeach;?>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
/*Card deck*/
.card-deck {
 margin-left: -8px;
 margin-right: 0!important;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card-img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.card-img__header {
 margin: 20px 20px 0;
}

.card-img__product {
 min-height: 175px;
 line-height: 175px;
}

.card-like {
  background: url("../img/like-blue-icon.png") 50% 50%/1.8rem no-repeat;
  margin-left: .2rem;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-like.active {
  background: url("../img/like-full_blue-icon.png") 50% 50%/1.8rem no-repeat;
}

.card-hit {
  display: none;
}

.card-hit.active {
  display: block;
  font-size: .9rem;
  margin-right: .2rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  color: #fff;
  background: #e39138;
  padding: .2rem 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}


.card-img__product img {
 max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.card-deck .card {
 margin: 8px;
}

.card {
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 border: 1px solid #edeff1;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 13px;
}

.card-body {
 padding: 15px;
}

.card-title {
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #414E71;
}

.card-text {
 margin: 30px 0 20px;
}

.card-text p {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.card-price {
 font-size: 13px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.card-price p {
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-right: 3px;
}

.card-price h4 {
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил с помощью добавления свойства в стили.

```css
.card-deck .card {
 margin: 0 1%;
 flex: 0 1 22%;
}
```